# Visual SVN - getting the total size of all the repositories

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, visualsvn

Can I simply right-click on the root folder where the repositories are stored and view the size on disk? Im planning on moving the repositories to a new server and checking storage space requirements.  The size of the root path seems awful small compared to the working copies I have checked out.  Are they compressed as they are stored on the server path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can simply right-click the repositories root directoiry (e.g. C:\Repositories) and you'll see the size of your repos.

In addition to this, if you want to check the size of your repositories, use [`Measure-SvnRepository`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/#Measure-SvnRepository) PowerShell cmdlet. VisualSVN Server PowerShell cmdlets are available beginning with version 3.4, so make sure that your server is up to date. For information about other PowerShell cmdlets, read the article [KB88: VisualSVN Server PowerShell Cmdlet Reference](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/).

BTW, don't confuse [Subversion repository](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.basic.version-control-basics.html#svn.basic.repository) with a full [working copy checkout](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.basic.version-control-basics.html#svn.basic.working-copy) of this repository. Subversion repository use special space-saving techniques and in majority of cases it will be smaller than a fill working copy checkout of the repository. See [SVNBook | How Subversion saves disk space](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.diskspace.deltas).